# Update Excel Web App from Local Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pretty basic knowledge base of VBA. I've been using it the past year to write programs that copy the data from excel to websites.

Right now I have a local excel sheet full of data (which is updated daily), that I am trying to have automatically copied into the Excel Web App via VBA.

I'm hoping someone can tell me how to reference the cells in the Web App from my local VBA (assuming it's possible). I can't seem to find the answer anywhere else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Excel Web App opens files from OneDrive, therefor, saving the file in the OneDrive folder on your local machine will do what you ask.

All three of the following examples presume the purpose is to save a macro-enabled workbook as a macro-enabled workbook of the same name in the default OneDrive folder location "C:\Users\user\OneDrive"

The first two examples save a copy of the active workbook to OneDrive; in contrast, the third example moves the file without creating a copy and cannot be used if the file is open.

Example 1: save a copy of the active workbook to OneDrive. The original workbook remains the active workbook.  Subsequent changes remain with the original and are not applied to the copy in OneDrive.

```
Sub SaveCopyToOneDrive()
    Dim destinationFolder As String
    destinationFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs destinationFolder & ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

Example 2: save the active workbook in OneDrive.  The file in OneDrive becomes the active workbook and the original workbook is closed without saving.

```
Sub SaveToOneDrive()
    Dim destinationFolder As String
    destinationFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs destinationFolder & ActiveWorkbook.Name, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```

Example 3: move the file from an explicitly defined location to OneDrive.  The target file cannot be the VBA host for this macro.

```
Sub MoveToOneDrive()
    Dim shortFileName As String
    Dim fullFileName As String
    Dim destinationFolder As String
    fullFileName = "C:\MyDataFiles\File.xlsm"
    Name fullFileName As destinationFolder & shortFileName
    destinationFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\"
    shortFileName = Mid(fullFileName, InStrRev(fullFileName, Chr(92)) + 1, Len(fullFileName))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply How do I do this if the Excel file I am trying to update isn't on a drive I have access to? It's at our Headquarters and each unit under them has to update it from their location.

Comment: Yeah, I see I worked the problem backwards and provided the opposite of what you want.  From what little I know, the answer is likely predicated by the environment hosting the excel app.  For example, if you're viewing the file though a web browser then you can probably use the debugger to expose the elements and access them through VBA (pretty sure that's f12 in chrome and ie) but if you're using a standalone app or a plug-in then your visibility is likely obscured behind a bigger barrier and I don't have any suggestions to get through it